# Realtek AC600 linux setup

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux

I'm trying to install a wifi dongle on my arch-linux pc.

When I plug it in, it doesnt detect it:

```
# ~ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:cf:b0:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

So, as stated on the arch wiki, I installed `dkms` and `rtl88xxau-aircrack-dkms-git` package.

After doing that, I can see the device:

```
# ~ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:cf:b0:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp0s29u1u3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:e8:94:ca:8f:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


# ~ iw dev
phy#0
    Interface wlp0s29u1u3
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr 34:e8:94:ca:8f:05
        type managed
        txpower 0.00 dBm
```

But now, when I try to put it up I get:

```
# ~ ip link set wlp0s29u1u3 up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

rfkill is not the problem here:

```
# ~ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Of course, wpa_supplicant isn't connecting either:

```
# ~ wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp0s29u1u3
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Could not set interface wlp0s29u1u3 flags (UP): Operation not permitted
nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlp0s29u1u3' UP
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp0s29u1u3 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlp0s29u1u3: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

Any ideas on whats the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Tried to install rtl8812au-dkms-git before playing with rtl88xxau-aircrack-dkms-git ?

Comment: I tried with all the drivers on the arch linux wiki, and then I compiled every single one I could find on github with a similar name. None of them works. With some of them I managed to get the interface up, but it wasn't transmitting or connecting to anything. Even scanning for networks returned empty results. So I gave up, returned the device and bought an ethernet cable instead.